# How to block some requests with HTTP2

Tags: browser, tcp, http2, nghttp2

Now I want to build a middleware to process requests sent from browser, filter some of them then pass other to server(e.g. the middleware receive stream 1 and stream 3, it blocks 1 then pass 3 to the server).

I try to use GOAWAY to implement this but not ideal. It is expected that browser receives GOAWAY with last stream ID 1 and establish a new connection to send original stream 3. However general circumstance is that it will skip the stream 3 and send following requests
[image]

Another problem is that the browser will stop establishing new connection after sending requests for several times

Please give me some advice

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/2 is multiplexed, and one connection carries several HTTP/2 streams, each representing a request/response.

For this reason, you do not want to use GOAWAY, because that tears down the whole connection.

HTTP/2 has another way of canceling a specific stream, via the [RST_STREAM frame](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9113.html#name-rst_stream).

If your middleware application wants to filter out stream #1, it can send back to the browser a RST_STREAM frame for stream #1, and the browser will stop sending data (if any) for that stream.

Stream #3 will be unaffected, as future streams (on the same connection) will also be unaffected.

Your middleware can forward stream #3, #5, filter out #7 with another RST_STREAM, but forward #9, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In theory, using RST_STREAM is correct, but I encountered some issues when I tried it before. The first problem is that, as a middleware, it needs to maintain the offset of TCP's sequence and ack to adjust the sequence numbers of data between the client and the server. The second problem is that the client will send an ack for the RST_STREAM sent by the middleware. In usual cases, I would discard these ack packets, but if they carry data, it could be problematic. There are other considerations as well.

Comment: Now, I am thinking of using another method, which is to use GOAWAY to inform the client not to send data when encountering a packet that needs to be blocked. Then, after the server sends the requested data to the client, the client closes this connection and opens a new one to request unreplied or other data. I am not sure if this solution is feasible

Comment: It's not clear at what level you are working. If you use a library for HTTP/2, or you use a TCP library, then you don't need to maintain TCP sequences and ACKs, etc.
If you are re-implementing TCP then yes, you need to re-implement TCP, but chances are that you don't have to, you just rely on the OS implementation of TCP and use Posix for TCP sockets (if you have re-implemented HTTP/2).
If you use an HTTP/2 library, then you have to worry even less, and you just send the RST_STREAMs, and the library will do the rest.
Using GOAWAY is not the right solution.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, it helps me a lot